# fixed navbar overlaps content

Tags: html, css

I have a navbar that is fixed but also at certain times hidden. Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/edsm3g8o/ and the couple_text gets overlapped by the nav_header. I tried adding padding-top to the couple_text but when the nav_bar is hidden it looks like a lot of whitespace on top.

```
<ul class="nav_header">
    <li class="three liMoreShopping" style="display: table-cell;">
        <a class="btnMoreShopping ui-link"><span>More Shopping</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="three liCheckout" style="display: table-cell;">
         <a class="btnCheckout ui-link"><span>Checkout</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="three liCart" style="display: table-cell;">
         <a class="btnCart ui-link"><span>Cart (1)</span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="couple_text">
    <h3>Jane Doe, John Doe</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: use `javascript` or `jquery` to add `padding-top` == `height` of `ul`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there is another *(better?)* solution but if you are triggering the appearance/disappearance of the navbar with Javascript, maybe you can modify it to also toggle the padding, so it doesn't show up when the navbar is hidden and it's not needed.